# change report sample size on MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb, compass

I am wondering if there is a way when watching your DB collection with compass and you try to see it as Schema to change the report sample size because my current documents are let's say 5000, and the report is based on 1000.

It would be useful for me to visualize correctly a statistic data I am gathering and if it is not possible I would have to write my own visualization.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sampleSize is set to 1000 documents by default and cannot be changed in MongoDB Compass.

If you are using MongoDB Atlas you will probably want to use [Mongo Charts](https://charts.mongodb.com). You will need to create charts using the object ID and a specified field.

Otherwise, You will need to install [Navicat for MongoDB](https://navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mongodb) for more comprehensive schema options.